# Pasting files and concatating files together

Tags: shell-script, process, data, table

I have various years and months of data for numerous site locations. I have computed the average for all months for each needed year. Each Month/Year has its own its own file. Not all sites have data for a given month so no file exists in that case. What I am attempting to do is take each file Month/Year to build a new file for each site. The file structure I am attempting to build would be

| Year | Jan | Feb |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2002 | xxx | xxx |
| 2003 | xxx | xxx |
| 2019 | xxx | xxx |

the naming conventions of the files are
County071-O3-5001-**2002**.out-**APR**.csv.tmp.ext-avg.dat with the **Bold** text which would change depending on the year and the month. Since there are missing "Months" and Years" data
at times I am unsure how to build table to account for missing months of data. Any suggestions how to automate this  would be great given I have over 100 sites to do for a 17 year period of time.

Thanks

Comment: Build table unconditionally first, then fill with data later on as appropriate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

without writing the code, I would use perl to write something to iterate across all of the possible months and years; plug those values into something that will be a file name and stat the file; if the file isn't found, assume that the data are zero for that month/year and move on to the next month/year.

Pseudo code:

```
foreach $year (2001 2002 2003 2004)
  foreach $month (Jan Feb Mar Apr Jun Jul Aug Sep Oct Nov Dec)
     if (-3 County071-O3-5001-$year).out-$month.csv.tmp.ext-avg.dat) /* test if it exists */
        then open it, read it, print it
     else  /* assume it's zero */
         print 0 
end
```